# --disable-web-security not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have two machines running Chrome 58.0.3029.81 (64 bit)

I kill all Chrome processes and run

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

It works on one but not the other.. 
Why does the problem machine display the following message:

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer.
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify `--user-data-dir`

`chrome_content_browser_client.cc(2639)] Web security may only be disabled if '--user-data-dir' is also specified.`